# How to set up GoCode for GoClipse?

Tags: eclipse, go, goclipse

After reading the guide on https://github.com/nsf/gocode, I tried the command `go get -u -ldflags -H=windowsgui github.com/nsf/gocode`. I don't get any response after this command.

[image]

I also found that there is a place in GoClipse that can let me input the path of GoCode. So, I think maybe I already have GoCode in my windows pc but what is its location?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`go get` won't output anything unless there's an error.

The location for anything you install with the go tools is `$GOPATH/bin`, `$GOPATH` depends on your environment.

If you're not sure where it is, run `go env` and it will print a list of the environment variables that Go uses, including GOPATH.

Answer (score 1):

just go to the command line and type: go env

Navigate to GOPATH directory in windows, you will find bin folder underneath, open the folder, you will see all the required exe files installed, just mentioned them in eclipse,
Example from my env:

- Check the GOPATH folder

[image]

- Navigate to the GOPATH folder\bin, and make sure that the required exe file are installed
  [image]
- Set the exe paths in eclipse

[image]

- Here is the result
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to Window -> Preferences -> Go -> Tools
Easiest and quickest way is to click the download buttons under *gocode, guru and godef*.
Eclipse will automatically do the rest of things for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One quick addition to the other answers suggesting to using the Download buttons in Eclipse to download gocode, guru and godef.

The commands produced by Eclipse are no longer working as go get is deprecated.

Use these commands instead (via cmd).

- "C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe" install github.com/nsf/gocode@latest
- "C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe" install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru@latest
- "C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe" install github.com/rogpeppe/godef@latest

Then browse in Eclipse (Window -> Preferences -> Go -> Tools) for the respective .exe files:

[image]